# JQuery select2 (4.0.9) raise event in dynamic table or get is:('focus')

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a table dynamic  with control in it.The id of all controls in this  are generated client side and getting the id like name_of_control# which '#' is the row number...

I'm creating the row client side with a ajax call and append it the the table:

```
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../FormConsist/AddNewRow',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });

    $("#table").append(result);
```

Some of the element in the  generated dynamic can post back on the server.
Like a select element standard ,which work fine via is(:focus), but don't work on the select2 one.
I can't get the `.is(':focus')` value (true or false) on the select2.
So, I'm checking if element have change like that:

```
$(document).on("change", "#table tr", function () {
    var row_index = $(this).index() + 1;

    if ($(this).find('#drop' + row_index).is(':focus')) {
       alert(''); //work select standard
    }

    $(this).find('#drop' + row_index)is(':focus')) {
        alert('');//this don't work!!! It's a select 2 drop down
    });
});
```

How can i know when the 'select 2' change value? Could a event could be bind on a 'select 2' which i don't have the id until the row of the table is create?

Maybe

```
$(document).on("change", "#table tr", function (){...}
```

is not the way to verify if the control in this row have change.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, if found a solution:

$(document).on("change", '[id^=control#]', function (e) { ... }

Will raise a event when the select2 change is value!
That way each dropdown starting with a id 'control#' are going to raise.